# ajax-solr: How to make an ajax page readable by Google?

Tags: ajax, solr, web-crawler, google-ajax

I am using [ajax-solr](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr) to generate search results from Solr.

Is there any way to make such an ajax page available to Google (and search engines in general) for indexing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how this maps to ajax-solr specifically, but take a look at "[Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/learn-more.html)", it explains how googlebot can crawl and index ajax websites.

Still, I think the safest way is to implement *graceful degradation* of ajax functions, unfortunately I don't think this is doable in a pure ajax-solr site.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to use [Google Sitemaps](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) and create alternative representations of the Solr database's contents (i.e. have one URL for each document in the Solr database). In other words, don't try to make make the ajax-solr page indexable by Google.